# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null" Cual es el error de este código y que agregarían para solucionarlo

Tags: javascript

El error es el siguiente:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null"

Acá el codigo.
No puedo solucionarlo, si alguien es tan amable y me ayuda! Se los agradezco. Saludos.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
#container {
  width: 320px;
  height: 220px;
  position: relative;
  background: black;
}
#animate {
  width: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
}
</style>
<body>
 
<div id ="container">
  <div id ="animate"></div>
</div>
<p><button onclick="magicFunction()">Click</button></p>

<script>
function magicFunction() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("absolute");   
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 5);
  function frame() {
    if (pos == 320) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos++; 
      elem.style.left = pos + "px"; 
    }
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Estás intentando ingresar a la `propiedad` de un elemento inexistente con el `identificador` **absolute**. Por esa razón te indica el `error`.

```
var elem = document.getElementById("absolute");
```

Los únicos elementos con `identificador` son `container` y `animate`:

```
<div id ="container">
<div id ="animate"></div>
```

Intenta cambiar el nombre del identificador en esta línea por `identificadores` válidos:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("container");
```

ó

```
var elem = document.getElementById("animate");
```

Ya que esos `elementos` sí existen y sí se les está aplicando `estilo`. Pruébalo.